# NoClassDefFoundError after multidexing

Tags: android, android-multidex

I implemented multidexing after getting 65k method limit. After implementing multidexing I am able to run application. But now i am getting the error NoClasDefFoundError for one of the class I used from external jar.

Here is my gradle file--

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':pull-to-refresh')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':gson-2.2.2')
    compile files('libs/android-support-multidex.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
            } else {
                dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'`enter code here`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide you source hows you implement multidexing ?

Comment: I'm having what sounds like this problem as well. To add more details: I call `MultiDex.install()` in `attachBaseConext()` in my Application subclass, and I can see output in the log indicating that it's installing, and finding classes2.dex. I can run large parts of the application normally -- it's not crashing because classes referenced by my Application subclass are missing -- but when it calls into a 3rd-party library method in the secondary dex, I get the NoClassDefFoundError. I am not using `--main-dex-list` in my dx invocation.

Comment: Sorry for the second comment; I can no longer edit the first. It turns out that multidexing doesn't work well with Java code called only via JNI. Even if you use a `--main-dex-list` to keep all the classes called from native in one dex, that doesn't trigger the rewriting of call sites in those classes methods. You'd have to add every class referenced down every code path to the main dex list to get it to work, which probably defeats the purpose of using multidex anyway, and is quite fragile against even internal API changes in the library.

Comment: Thanks for reply @icodestuff but how to add class referenced down every code path to the main dex list to get it to work

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by making sure that the MultiDex.install line is AFTER the call to super.attachBaseContext. If you call install before super.attach, apparently it doesn't register correctly. **However, it's probably a better alternative to simply change your application class to extend MultiDexApplication instead of Application.**

**Note:** after you extend MultiDexApplication, you NO LONGER need to override attachBaseContext and call MultiDex.install(this). If you look at the source code of MultiDexApplication ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/1bb1ab007f6b9405227ea4ce07d2061e4dbb6fe0/library/src/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.java)) you will see that the entire purpose of this class is to call install for you.

The official instructions from Google ([posted here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)) point you to the documentation for MultiDexApplication ([posted here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)) and that page contains instructions with multiple options to solve this but I missed that the first time through so I'm sure many others will as well.

Answer (score 3):

This happened in one of our Android projects that is multi-dex enabled and that was already properly set up (it calls MultiDex.install after super.attachBaseContext(...) as it is supposed to).

It was tracked down to a private static inner class that we were using to implement the initialization-on-demand holder idiom design pattern (lazy loaded singleton). Apparently that class was not being included in the primary dex file which resulted in the NoClassDefFoundError.

We ended up just making the singleton class an enum.